# MBProgressHUD Completed View with Checkmark

Tags: ios

I am using [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) and I want to change the appearance to the one which has checkmark and the completed text. Any ideas how I can do that?

[image]

Comment: Checkthe  MBProgressHUD doc, or example...

Comment: Docs are vey limited and their example code does not even run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there is no built in appearance like the one on the screenshot. you have to provide your own checkmark image. Then you can change the appearance like this:

```
let hud = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(view, animated: true)
hud.mode = .CustomView
hud.customView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "checkmark")) // according to the documentation a good image size is something like 37x37px
hud.label.text = "Completed"
```

[image: checkmark]